# Delete data doesn´t work, SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a row from SQLite, but i cant, Eclipse don´t say me nothing error. I can insert, and delete all, but when i am going to delete a row, do nothing

```
public void AlertDialogLimpiarProducto(final int position){
            AlertDialog.Builder aviso = new AlertDialog.Builder(Carrito.this);  
            aviso.setTitle("Alerta");  
            aviso.setMessage("¿Desea borrar el producto?");            
            aviso.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {  
                    try{
                        db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
                        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Carrito WHERE nombre = '" + nombre_producto +"'");
                        cuentas.remove(position);
                        //PARA BAJAR EL CONTADOR DEL ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL
                        MainActivity.contador_carrito--;
                        MainActivity.cantidad_carrito.setText(MainActivity.contador_carrito+"");
                        Toast.makeText(Carrito.this, nombre_producto+" eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        db = usdbh.getReadableDatabase();
                        db.close();

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }  
            });  
            aviso.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);            
            aviso.show();
        }
```

Comment: try this `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Carrito WHERE nombre = '" + nombre_producto+"'");`

Comment: try this `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Carrito WHERE nombre = '" + nombre_producto+"'");`

Comment: does not work, but is one of the mistakes thanks!, don't delete and the toast does not show too

Comment: `System.out.println ( "OK" );` write this line as first line in try block and check if your try block is running or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally it should work with execSQL if its not working with your device
please try use the method delete

```
db.delete(table_name, where, whereArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with : db.delete("Carrito", "nombre = ?", new String[]{nombre_producto});

Answer (score 0):

Your delete query is incomplete

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Carrito WHERE nombre = '" + nombre_producto);
```

I assume `nombre_producto` is of type String so your delete query should be like below,

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Carrito WHERE nombre = '" + nombre_producto  + "'" ) ;
```

Comment: does not work, but is one of the mistakes thanks!, don't delete and the toast does not show